# jquery for ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I am tying to use this code http://gist.github.com/110410 to dump Prototype in favor of jQuery but I do have a problem.

This is my HTML (a link_to generated link):

```
<a onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href;var s = document.createElement('input'); s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); s.setAttribute('value', 'Mi6RcR6YDyvg2uNwGrpbeIJutSHa2fYboU37wSDE7AU='); f.appendChild(s);f.submit();return false;" class="post add_to_cart " href="/line_items?product_id=547">Add to cart</a>
```

Issue:

Everything works as it should except that the page does a reload. I suspect that the submit gets thru which causes a page reload.

Is there an elegant way to prevent that ? return false; doesn't seem to cut it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

ew. Use this (jQuery):

```
<a class="post add_to_cart" rel="Mi6RcR6YDyvg2uNwGrpbeIJutSHa2fYboU37wSDE7AU=" href="/line_items?product_id=547">Add to cart</a>
<script>
    $("a.add_to_cart").click(function(){
        $.post(this.href,{'authenticity_token':$(this).attr("rel")});
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I put the authenticity token in the rel attr for the anchor assuming the token is unique to the product.

---

**UPDATE**

Because apparently Rails gives you no control of anything at all:

```
<a class="post add_to_cart" href="/line_items?product_id=547" onclick='            $.post(this.href,{"authenticity_token":"Mi6RcR6YDyvg2uNwGrpbeIJutSHa2fYboU37wSDE7AU="});return false;'>Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: the entire onclick part is generated by a rails helper so I don't have to much control over that also, I wanna keep it for non javascript browsers. is there a way to intercept that submit without changing my html code ?

Comment: I had no idea rails sucked so badly.

Comment: You want to keep what for non-javascript browsers? the javascript? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: the method you provided is still obtrusive, I don't wanna manually construct my link, I just wanna override the default link constructed by the rails helper. also if you disable javascript in your browser, that link won't pass the token.

Comment: You do realize that what you are asking is not possible. An anchor element cannot perform a form POST (without javascript). Just put the auth token in the url.